# Bitwise operators and bit manipulation (no solution?)

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

I've been racking my brain trying to come up with a solution, but am stuck.

I have a function, this function takes the input (either `0b0`, `0b1`, or `0b10`) and sets the bit of some variable - or at least it's supposed to.

The value it's changing has two states: either `0b100` or `0b101`. I want to set the respective bit from the input. This is easy for the true bits, but tricky for the false bits. Some pseudo code for all the scenarios:

```
if (var == 0b100 && input == 0b0) { do nothing }   // bit already set
if (var == 0b101 && input == 0b0) { var = 0b100 }  // bit is different, so we set it.

if (var == 0b100 && input == 0b1) { var = 0b101 }  // bit is different, so we set it.
if (var == 0b101 && input == 0b1) { do nothing }   // bit is already set

if (var == 0b100 && input == 0b10) { var = 0b110 } // bit is never set, so set it
if (var == 0b101 && input == 0b10) { var = 0b110 } // bit is never set, so set it
```

I don't want to cheat and make a separate statement for every possibility, I'd like a function for this. Here's what I've sort of strung together, but it obviously doesn't work:

```
if ( var ^ input )
{
    var ^= input;
}
```

The issue with this code is that 3rd bit (far left one) is always true.

Is this even possible?

## **EDIT:**

Here is the same question, just posed a different way (which will result in different answers).

A function takes input for one bit. I want to take the left most bit and compare that bit and only that bit to another variable. e.g. `input = 0b10` compared to `0b101`'s second bit, `0b00`, since `0b10`'s left most bit is the second one.

On rare occasion, the unchanging bit may change :P (not from me though), so `0b001` or `0b000` may be it's value. For this reason, I cannot create a dynamic mask and compare only my bit.. The best method to solve my issue would be to answer this alternative question. Thanks a ton for your help, guys!

Comment: As I see it, all you need to do is `var = 0b100 | input`.

Comment: I plan to make the cases more dynamic than just `0b100`. This is as simple of an example that I could come up with. Something that avoids hard coding the unchanging parts would be awesome. I also don't want to attempt to set the variable unless there is a change that's going to happen. (e.g. var != input) Sorry for all the weird rules! Hopefully this example includes all the possible cases (unchanging, always set, dynamic).

Comment: There are tons of tools for this sort of thing, including the bitwise operators, shift operators to turn the input into a bit index, moving to a state machine, or using boolean logic minimization tools such as Karnaugh maps. Without some actual information on what you are really trying to do, it is fairly hard to give a good answer.

Comment: Right, well I was hoping that wasn't the case :( Anyway, I'm writing to memory of another program, and I don't want to write if it's unnecessary. I'm doing a check to see if it's current state is different than what I want to set it to (`var ^ input`) but that isn't actually going to work because of the unchanging bits. One bit is never on, and when switched on, is only on for a millisecond to complete an action. The last bit is togglable. The variable is an unsigned int, but only the last X bits are actually useful. This question includes all the scenarios I encounter.

Comment: There are more bits than just that last bit I'm toggling in the actual scenario. If you'd like, I can change the example to be 8 bits long, 2 always on (unchangable), 3 changing, and 3 always off (changeable). Maybe it'll help people from answering specific example case questions. I'm new here, so I'm sorry :)

Comment: What you do in your example above is `var = 0b100 + input`. Is that right?

Comment: hmmm, maybe! :D I'll test and report back. If it works, I guess I just need a way to automate ignoring the unchanging bits (as they change every time the program launches). Whatever! :) **EDIT:** No, that won't work as it'll shift the bits if there are some on in between INPUT and the end of VAR

Comment: The input is always focused on one bit, by the way! So if there's a way to isolate and check a bit, that'd be great! :)

Comment: You say that `var` is always either `0b100` or `0b101`, but then you violate that in the last two lines, setting it to `0b110`.  So without more information as to what should happen when `var` is `0b110` (or any other value), your question can't really be answered.

Comment: Right, I violate it, and the program changes it back (after doing the instruction stored in that bit). When I read that `var`, it's always `0b100` or `0b101`. I updated the question and posed it in a different way.

Comment: What is the nature of `var`? Is it memory mapped I/O? Like hardware register?

Comment: It's an array of flags. bit 1, the farthest bit to the right, determines whether X feature is on. bit 2, 1 left from bit 1, determines if X feature is on for 1 millisecond, then disables it. bit 3 - 25 determine other things. bit 26 determines feature y, bit 27 determines if feature y is on for 1 millisecond, then disables it. etc... It's set as an Unsigned long. There are more in the program I need to manipulate, so I'd like a good grasp on what to do before I tackle the problem.

Comment: I repeat: Is it memory mapped I/O?

Comment: No, it is not (from the programs side). Writing to it externally (in/out) is not intended, but the program is outdated and barely works, so I'm creating something to manipulate the memory to get it working again. So far, so good - this is the only hang I'm having. I suppose, technically, from my side, yeah, it is memory mapped i/o.

Comment: Is `var` atomic?

Comment: No, but my copy of it is. (`std::atomic<unsigned int> myvar = read(theirvar)`, where their var is just unsigned int.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Mask out the lower two bits.

```
var &= 0b100;
```

Step 2: Assign the lower two bits through OR operation.

```
var |= input;
```

Note that you may need to change the bit mask in step 1 in actual code base on the actual data type.

Comment: I'd prefer to not set the variable unnecessarily without knowing that it's changed :D Say the input is `0b101` and the var is `0b101`, I'd be setting var to `0b101` even though it was already that.

Comment: @J.Doe Your question say the input is either `0b0`, `0b1`, or `0b10`. Checking validity of input is a separate action outside these two steps. And why do you want to avoid setting the variable "unnecessarily"?

Comment: I explained it in reply to someone else, but I'm writing to another programs memory. Doing so unnecessarily is dangerous for this program, so I want to avoid doing it all together.

Comment: Unless the final result depends on the value already in the bits in question there is no reason to check their value beforehand. Some operations that does make sense ((some string operations come to mind) but bit wise operations are so basic you would pretty much have to have duplicate code at the asm level to check the value before assigning.

Comment: If the intermediate step is worying someone, just combine the two binary operations in a single step

Comment: If you want to prevent writing to the variable in the other program's memory, compute the result as in this answer, then compare it with the original value, and if it changed, write it to the memory location.